# ¿Cómo hacer una Exception por límites de un vector?

Tags: java, netbeans, consola, excepciones

Buenas noches.
He estado realizando una tarea y me he topado con errores en tiempo de ejecución cuando sobrepaso el límite de un vector. 
Estuve investigando y encontré que eso podría resolverlo con try-catch pero en mí código no funciona como debería.

```
   try {
            System.out.print("Ingresar la coordenada horizontal (1-5): ");
            x = entrada.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Ingresar la coordenada vertical (1-10): ");
            y = entrada.nextInt();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("No está dentro del rango");
        }
```

A pesar de que colocado el try-catch sigue mostrándome un error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
```

He intentado de esta otra forma según logre encontrar pero sigue mostrándome el mismo error de ejecución.

```
  try {
            System.out.print("Ingresar la coordenada horizontal (1-5): ");
            x = entrada.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Ingresar la coordenada vertical (1-10): ");
            y = entrada.nextInt();

        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("No está dentro del rango");
        }
```

Alguna sugerencia para poder resolver este problema en los limites del vector.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Podrías poner el código completo. O al menos el código alrededor de la línea que produce el error.

Comment: Me parece que deberías utilizar `x-1` e `y-1` cuando quieres colocar el dato en tu arreglo.

Answer (score 0):

No se donde pongas la asignación de las variables al vector, pero deben de ir dentro del bloque de try, tal vez por eso no esta cachando la excepción

```
 try {
            System.out.print("Ingresar la coordenada horizontal (1-5): ");
            x = entrada.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Ingresar la coordenada vertical (1-10): ");
            y = entrada.nextInt();
            //asignacion de las variables x & y al vector 


        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("No está dentro del rango");
        }
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero no me ha funcionado, además de que (x, y) las uso globalmente.

Comment: pon la parte de codigo donde asignas datos al vector, para ver si te podemos ayudar mas claramente

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que realizar la asignación dentro del bloque try. Así, si las variables 'x' y 'y' sobrepasan los límites del vector, el bloque catch atrapará la excepción.

```
try {
    System.out.print("Ingresar la coordenada horizontal (1-5): ");
    x = entrada.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Ingresar la coordenada vertical (1-10): ");
    y = entrada.nextInt();

    vector[x][y] = 5; // Asignamos valor dentro del bloque try.

}
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    System.out.println("No está dentro del rango");
}
```

Asumiendo, claro, que el array/vector es bidimensional (dado que pides dos coordenadas) y es del tipo entero.

Answer (score 0):

No me estaba funcionando muy bien el código porque no estaba atrapando en ningún lugar la exception. El método donde estaba creando el error es parte de una case por lo tanto no sabía donde estaría el error. Ahora he puesto el try-catch en el case donde se encuentra mi método.

```
     switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                    System.out.println("\n*************************************");
                System.out.print(nombre + " ha seleccionado el nivel **PRIMERO**");


                try{
                    Jugar();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Ingreso fuera de los límites...");
                }


                break;
```

Luego en la sección donde se espera hacer una Exception :

```
   public void Jugar() {

    LlenarFacil();


        System.out.print("Ingresar la coordenada horizontal (1-15): ");

        x = entrada.nextInt();

        while(x > 15){
            System.out.print("NO puede ser mayor a 15, ingrese de nuevo: ");
            x = entrada.nextInt();
        }
```

Ésto se ejecutará tantas veces hasta que el usuario ingrese un correcto rango.